# hostname error when creating azure data factory linked service using shopify (preview) CONNECTOR

Tags: azure-data-factory, shopify-api

I am trying to setup an integration to shopify using azure data factory since there is a shopify preview connector, however i cannot establish the linked service. I keep getting a cannot resolve hostname error. I am able to create a connection using the REST API service but it will not work using the shopify connector. I am using this host name https://joyfolie.myshopify.com/

Error code
9603
Details
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Shopify] (20) Error while attempting to use REST API: Couldn't resolve host name ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Shopify] (20) Error while attempting to use REST API: Couldn't resolve host name Activity ID: e0d3dcab-8a2b-4ebe-bde5-c6cd9de3d1f2.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all: Couldn't resolve host name.
This means that your local machine/server is unable to communicate.

**Workaround -**

Please test with Postman to confirm if you were able to establish connection successfully. If your test connection with Postman is failing then there could be some authorization issue with access token.

In case if you are able to test connection successfully then there could be something wrong in ADF linked service. If that is the case I would recommend you to raise a [support ticket](http://%20https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You just need to remove the leading "https://"

The placeholder text shown in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-shopify?tabs=data-factory) does not include the protocol.